# Flutter with Redux: How to show alert from middleware? Where can i get BuildContext

Tags: android, redux, flutter

In my chat app on Flutter with Redux architecture I need to show dialog after result of some async call. My main problem is to get current BuildContext for show dialog. And this async call can be done from different screens, and i need context of current screen.

My call on Middleware side looks like:

```
void _setCompanionToChat(String groupChatId) {

  var documentReference = _getChatDocument(groupChatId);

  documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
     var closed = snapshot[ChatDatabase.CLOSED_ATTRIBUTE];

     if (snapshot.exists && !closed) {
         // SOME OPERATIONS
     } else {
        //  SHOW DIALOG
     }
  });
}
```

Any advices how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can pass your dialog as a callback:

- Create your request actions in this way:

```
class MyDataRequestAction {
  ...
  Function onError;
  MyDataRequestAction({this.onError});
}
```

- In your screens, dispatch those actions in a StoreConnector, e.g.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  StoreConnector<AppState, _MyScreenViewModel>(
  onInit: (store) => store.dispatch(MyDataRequestAction(
    onError: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(...));
  ));
  ...
```

- and finally in your middleware:

```
class MyMiddleware extends MiddlewareClass<AppState> {
  ...
  @override
  void call(Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
    ...
    _setCompanionToChat(groupChatId, action) // PASS THE ACTION!!
  }

  void _setCompanionToChat(String groupChatId, dynamic action) {
    ...
    if (snapshot.exists && !closed) {
      // SOME OPERATIONS
    } else {
      action.onError();
    }
```